# How to get data from Firestore in map function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve data from Firestore as I map through an object to see if the user is online. I'm not sure how to retrieve the data.

When I console.log userInLobby (as shown below), I get [Promise] array.

If I try to set a variable before the firebase call, I cannot change the variable inside the .then() function

```
 const userInLobby = users ? (
  users.map(userdata => {
    if (userdata.status === "online") {
      var user =
        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userdata.id).get().then(user => {
          return { username: user.data().username };
        })
      return user
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  })
) : (null);
```

How can I access the [Promise] or is there another way to structure this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run an asyncronous function (`firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userdata.id).get()`) inside a map function.

That won't work. The map function will just return an array of promises.

What you need to do is use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get the result when all the promises return.

```
const userInLobby = users
  && users.map(userdata => {
      if (userdata.status === 'online') {
        return firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userdata.id)
          .get()
      } 
    })

Promise.all(userInLobby).then(values => console.log(values))
```